# Java MongoDB doesn't return null

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a problem where when record I search for exists, the query returns result without issues, but when I search for something that doesn't exist it doesn't return `null`, it just does nothing. Silently fails and doesn't execute rest of the code.

My query simply looks like this:

`Document contact = contacts.find(eq("_id", new ObjectId(customerID))).first();`

FIGURED IT OUT: String MUST be hex otherwise the query will silently fail.

Comment: What do you mean by "silently fails, doesn't execute the rest of the code"? Are you sure that there is no exception (that you are maybe try-ignoring)? Or is the query still running?

Comment: There is no exception code in method definition or any `try/catch` clauses. Server keeps on running, but if I put `System.out.println()` straight after my `contacts.find()` it never prints anything.

Comment: If there is no record, how do expect it to return first? this is error

Comment: @Kami Can you elaborate how does this silently fail in case of invalid hex ? Below code in ObjectId throws exception in case of invalid hex. https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/169aa0c5db4387874b62005672ebdf529e9905c9/bson/src/main/org/bson/types/ObjectId.java#L522

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Document contact = contacts.find(eq("_id", new ObjectId(customerID))).first();`

Change it to (You can optimize it. I'm doing top of my head)

```
if(contacts.find(eq("_id", new ObjectId(customerID)))! = null)
{
    Document contract = contacts.find(eq("_id", new ObjectId(customerID))).first();
}
```

Comment: FindIterable is already null result proof. https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/3ffbe70a70a09f4e7a081922b20e8cdef444c1d5/driver/src/main/com/mongodb/FindIterableImpl.java#L205

Comment: @nobody, I'm sorry, I didn't get it. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Oh, I got it. thanks. I was saying if there is no result, how once can expect first()? first mean there should be atleast one record. am i right?

Comment: No, you are wrong. I figured out issue tho, string must be hex, otherwise it will silently fail.

Comment: Well, I have no way to know what are you passing. Anyway, good find.